# Composing observables in RxJava Android

Tags: android

I've been adapting my Android app to use RxJava but I'm having a little bit of trouble doing so. As I had been advised in a previous post ([Wait for all requests in Android Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108391/wait-for-all-requests-in-android-volley)), I'm using Observables to mimic how I'm interfacing with my REST API in JavaScript. Specifically, using the promise library, I compose calls like this:

```
$q.all([
   fetchResourceA(),
   fetchResourceB()
])
  .then(function (responses) {
     ...
     return fetchResourceC();
  })
  .then(function (response) {
     ...
  });
```

In this example, I query two resources simultaneously, collect the results, then collect a third resource based on some of the parameters from the previously collected resources. The best I've been able to do to mimic this in RxJava is like this:

```
Observable o = Observable.zip(
   fetchResourceA(),
   fetchResourceB(),
   new Func2<ResA, ResB, Object>() {
      @Override
      public Object call(ResA resA, ResB resB) {
         ...
      }
   }
);
```

But I'm struggling to compose them like I did in JavaScript. Do I need to simply create a second observable and subscribe to it in the callback of the zip? That's what I'm doing now, and it works, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant and more reactive-appropriate way to structure my requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.then` method from promise can be transposed to `flatMap` method in RxJava

So, what you can do, is to `zip` then `flatMap` then `flatMap`

```
Observable.zip(fetchA(), fetchB(), (a, b) -> new Response(a, b))
          .flatMap((responses) -> fetchC())
          .flatMap((cResponse) -> /* whatever */)
          .subscribe();
```

Please note that `fetchA()`, `fetchB()`, `fetchC()` return Observables.

(My example use lambdas for clarity)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had tried flat maps but I must have made some mistake when attempting to chain them properly. Your example works and is exactly what I was looking for.